# 2 way-binding with a nested property inside object. (VueJS + VueX)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm currently doing the below:

```
<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    editingItem: {
      get() {
        return this.$store.getters['editing/editingItem'];
      },
      set(newValue) {
        this.$store.commit('editing/UPDATE_EDITING', newValue);
      }
    },
    editingItemName: {
      get() {
        return this.editingItem.name;
      },
      set(newValue) {
        this.editingItem.name = newValue;
        this.editingItem = this.editingItem;
      }
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Am I over complicating it? The second line on the editingItemName set(), is a workaround to make the editingItem set() function trigger.

Comment: can you explain what you are trying to acheive? are you trying to achieve 2-way data binding with store?

Comment: @LiranC Yeah. I can do it with a simple state value, but if it has nested parameters, I have to either do like I've done or have a commit for every parameter on the Store. The reason I did like the example is that this way I only have to have one Mutation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Check this article](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/forms.html). it's about forms, but it shows the way to achieve to 2-way binding with vuex.

regarding your special case, see the code. `telephone` is a nested property inside an object.

**myModule.js**

```
const myModule = {
  state: {
    customerInfo: {
      name: '',
      telephone: ''
    }
  },
  getters: {
    getTelephone(state) {
      return state.customerInfo.telephone
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    setTelephone(state, payload) {
      state.customerInfo.telephone += payload
    },
  }
}
export default myModule;
```

**form.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input v-model="telephone"></input>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    telephone: {
      get() {
        return this.$store.getters['getTelephone']
      },
      set(value) {
        this.$store.commit('setTelephone', value)
      }
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Cool. It looks like what I was doing - besides that I'm reusing the same mutation for every nested parameter. Do you think I should have one mutation to every parameter or what I'm doing is ok? Will mark your answer as correct as I do think that is the way to do it right now!